# Recieve firebase dynamic link suffic in onGenerateRoute in iOS flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

Suppose I clicked on a dynamic link like this https://jackui.me/znV8 (demo dynamic for ex)
then I receive /znv8 in my onGenerateRoute in the Material app and then on firebase dynamic listener I want to receive the resolved deep link in just firebase dynamic listener and I am unable to find out how I am receiving the dynamic URL suffix in onGenerateRoute I want to stop it

this is happening only in iOS iPhones, working fine on android

```
 MaterialApp(
              onGenerateRoute: (s) {
                 print(s); /// receiving here /znv8
              },
            ),
```

then received here the working deep link from dynamic URL

```
   FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((data) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, data.link.path);
        })
```

Comment: Did you figure out of this one? I have the same issue.

Comment: Facing the same issue, has anyone found a solution?

Comment: I am facing the same problem here! does anyone know how we can go deeper in the callback stack and know what line of code launched that route?

Comment: same question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73262332/flutter-ios-firebase-dynamic-link-push-named-page-with-the-link-value
is there anywhere else we can ask the question? no one is answering it on stack over flow

Comment: @ThomasVervik check out my answer, it might help you

Comment: @AymanBarghout check out my answer it might help you