# Flutter iOS Firebase dynamic link push named page with the link value

Tags: flutter, firebase, deep-linking, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Currently I am working with the Dynamic links from Firebase to implement the password reset function.

On Android everything is working fine and I am handling the deep link if the app get opened by it.

On iOS on the other hand it's also working, but the Flutter app pushes an extra named route with the value of the link. So if someone opens the app it automatically pushes a page with the named route "example.link.com".

How can I disable that?

Comment: I have the same problem
on iOS, it pushes an extra route to the stack
did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes i have the same problem but unfortunately i still haven't found a solution for it and because of that apple always rejects the app now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [issue open on FlutterFire](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9469) for this behavior, Flutter deep-linking and `firebase_dynamic_links` should work well together, but the reason is as follows:

On [this documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking) from flutter, it shows that to activate flutter deep linking on iOS, you need to add this to info.plist

```
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

and below it, there's a table showing the behavior of a flutter app with flutter deep linking enabled :
[image]

which is exactly what we are experiencing.
so removing that flag from my project's info.plist fixed my problem.

Comment: I suspected this might be the cause, thanks for confirming, but also on version `^2.0.0` of `firebase_dynamic_links` this issue doesn't happen, so something was introduced in the later versions, I suppose, that causes this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much! Removing these lines finally fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the **apple store id** and **bundle id** and **minimum version** in the IOSParameters

```
iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
    bundleId: "com.example.app.ios",
    appStoreId: "123456789",
    minimumVersion: "1.0.1",
  ),
```

Also put the appStoreId in the firebase project in **project settings**

Comment: where should I add iOS parameters?

Comment: in your code where you have defined links, here is the documentation -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/create